# InAppWebView is not working in flutter web app - Desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I have used InAppWebView plugin to load webview. It works fine in android and iOS. But in flutter web app, it throws error as plugin not supported.
Kindly suggest some solution or an plugin that works fine in all platforms.

Comment: InAppWebview or Webview isn't supported in Flutter Web.

Answer (score 1):

InAppWebview or Webview isn't supported in Flutter Web.

Check this package out: https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx

This is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webviewx/webviewx.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: WebViewX(
        initialContent: "https://flutter.dev/",
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: double.maxFinite,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you're not going to expand in your answer with code snippets (examples) then, please expand the comment you already did with this link. Users need to be able to have a full answer for their questions without leaving StackOverFlow.

Comment: Thanks @MarianoZorrilla, I've added an example.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. Looks way better.